# Android Authentication. Сохранение данных пользователя

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать Android client для веб сервиса. 
Возник такой вопрос: как правильно сделать авторизацию что бы арр сохранял  данные пользователя ? 
Есть для этого специальные либы или фреймворки ? Возможно ли это сделать при помощи Retrofit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать механизм самого Android для хранения аккаунта вашего приложения, в которых можно хранить какие то кастомные данные. Советую почитать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/company/e-Legion/blog/206210/)

Comment: Спасибо)  Полезная инфа!